To integrate arm64 hw watchpoint to linux process in C
I am looking at the Linux breakpoint test case, and try to understand it to put it into a Linux process
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/testing/selftests/breakpoints/breakpoint_test_arm64.c
what I don't understand is this function:

    static bool set_watchpoint(pid_t pid, int size, int wp)
    {
        const volatile uint8_t *addr = &var[32 + wp];
        const int offset = (uintptr_t)addr % 8;
        const unsigned int byte_mask = ((1 << size) - 1) << offset;
        const unsigned int type = 2; /* Write */
        const unsigned int enable = 1;
        const unsigned int control = byte_mask << 5 | type << 3 | enable;
        struct user_hwdebug_state dreg_state;
        struct iovec iov;

        memset(&dreg_state, 0, sizeof(dreg_state));
        dreg_state.dbg_regs[0].addr = (uintptr_t)(addr - offset);
        dreg_state.dbg_regs[0].ctrl = control;
        iov.iov_base = &dreg_state;
        iov.iov_len = offsetof(struct user_hwdebug_state, dbg_regs) + sizeof(dreg_state.dbg_regs[0]);
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGSET, pid, NT_ARM_HW_WATCH, &iov) == 0)
            return true;

        if (errno == EIO)
            ksft_print_msg("ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGSET, NT_ARM_HW_WATCH) not supported on this hardware: %s\n", strerror(errno));

        ksft_print_msg("ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGSET, NT_ARM_HW_WATCH) failed: %s\n",strerror(errno));

        return false;
    }


is dreg_state.dbg_regs[0].addr = (uintptr_t)(addr - offset); the address that watchpoint will be set on ?
here is my SUDO code and my understanding of the usage, please do correct me if I am wrong
    #include <sys/uio.h>
    #include <sys/user.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <sys/ptrace.h>
    #include <asm/ptrace.h>

    void ptrace_WP_set(pid_t child, uintptr_t address, size_t size) {
        const unsigned byte_mask = (1 << size) - 1;
        const unsigned type = 2; // Write.
        const unsigned enable = 1;
        const unsigned control = byte_mask << 5 | type << 3 | enable;

        struct user_hwdebug_state dreg_state;
        memset(&dreg_state, 0, sizeof dreg_state);
        dreg_state.dbg_regs[0].addr = address;
        dreg_state.dbg_regs[0].ctrl = control;
        struct iovec iov;
        iov.iov_base = &dreg_state;
        iov.iov_len = offsetof(struct user_hwdebug_state, dbg_regs) + sizeof(dreg_state.dbg_regs[0]);
        ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGSET, child, NT_ARM_HW_WATCH, &iov);
    }

    void run_WP (uintptr_t address){
        pid_t child = fork();
        int status;
        siginfo_t siginfo;

        if (child == 0) {
        
            //set so that parent can trace the children
            ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        
            //stop
            raise(SIGSTOP);
      
            //continue to return to main
            return;
        } else {
        
        }

        //wait for child and parent to be ready ?
        waitpid(pid, &status, __WALL);

        //set the watchpoint
        ptrace_WP_set(child, address, 16);
    
        //continue, as we stop the pid above with raise(SIGSTOP)
        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL);

        //wait for child and parent to hit the break point ?
        waitpid(pid, &status, __WALL);

        //get the breakpoint info
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, NULL, &siginfo);

        //kill the parent ?
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);

        //wait for parent to be kill ?
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}

    void main () {

        int a = 0;

        run_WP(&a);

        a = 3; //trigger the watchpoint ?

    }

many thanks in advance!

You appear to be looking at kernel tests, but you say that you want to write code for a process, which I take to imply something running in userspace.  Broadly speaking, kernel code is inappropriate for userspace, and userspace code is inappropriate for the kernel.  You cannot usefully integrate the test code you present into a userspace program.

@JohnBollinger The test case is userspace code.

var is not local to the function.

((1 << size) - 1) << offset is skunky code which will invoke UB in a lot of different scenarios...

@Lundin you are right, thanks
